# Why does OD matrix in sfnetwork returns one NA in dimension names?

Tags: r, matrix, tidygraph, sfnetwork

I have a rooted tree with spatially explicit edges representing a river network (`new_net`). I want to compute an origin-destination (OD) matrix to get the distances between multiple points representing small catchment outlets (1754 points) located on this river network.

I start by creating a network using my network dataset `hyriv_line`:

```
net <- as_sfnetwork(hyriv_line, directed = T)
```

Then I blend the outlet points (`dir_outlets`) to the network:

```
  # Update river network with outlets
  new_net <- net %>% # Original river network
    activate("nodes") %>%
    st_network_blend(dir_outlets) %>% # Blend in catchment outlets
    activate("edges") %>%
    mutate(weight = edge_length()) # Compute lenght of each river reach
```

Then I compute the OD matrix between all my outlet points:

```
  cost_matrix_out <- st_network_cost(new_net, 
                                 from = dir_outlets, to = dir_outlets, # from-to point sf
                                 mode = "out", # outbound (column-wise results)
                                 Inf_as_NaN = T)
```

It runs smoothly, but then, when looking at the resulting matrix, dimension names in rows appear with a leading X, meaning that something is wrong. One record —always the same, #823— looks like its name cannot be read properly, thereby adding NA instead in the OD matrix, hence the leading X. Column #823 in the matrix also has no name (see below).
[Snapshot of my OD matrix with NA is row name and empty column name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rcQj.png)

I can't make sense of it. I checked the point layer many times and its structure is sound. Any insight as to what I can further check?

Data for `dir_outlet` (where the name comes from):

```
dput(head(st_drop_geometry(dir_outlets[820:825,])), control = "showAttributes")
structure(list(c(7120213140, 7120933070, 7120213260, 7120933120, 
7120933150, 7120213350), c(7120933250, 7120213890, 7120213070, 
7120933570, 7120933230, 7120933250), c("7120213140", "7120933070", 
"7120213260", "7120933120", "7120933150", "7120213350")), .Names = c("from", 
"to", "name"), row.names = 820:825, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Taking one step further back, what did you use to read `hyriv_line` into your session and what would `dput(head(hyriv_line), n =3)` look like? Simplistically thinking it might be a unicode problem in the file...or...

Comment: sort of along this line [stringi canonical forrm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498789/convert-string-to-canonical-form-with-r), which shows test in action. Or, I could be completely wrong. But at least you know either the record (823) or perhaps it and it's neighbors to test.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your comments. I read `hyriv_line` using the `sf` package. Your bit of code returns an error. When I follow the test for canonical form, nothing alarming comes up:  
`>   str1 <- dir_outlets$name[823] 
>   str2 <- dir_outlets$name[822] 
>   charToRaw(str1)
 [1] 37 31 32 30 39 33 33 31 32 30
>   charToRaw(str2)
 [1] 37 31 32 30 32 31 33 32 36 30`

Comment: I'll continue to suggest you put some input data here, as all you're showing are outputs which makes it hard to reproduce or troubleshoot.

Comment: Sure. The point data is rather small, but I'm not sure what's the best way to share this input data here (sorry, newbie).

Comment: The `dput(head(hyriv_line), n = #some number of data lines)`, prints a `structure(`, play around with different number of data lines and sending through your process via `test1 <- structure('` copying to final `)`. Fish around for the amount of data that  is the min to demonstrate the problem, probably including the #[823], then copy that `structure(` to the bottom of your post under Data:, and people can just grab that structure and start playing around.

Comment: I think a dput of `hyriv_line/net` is also needed to complete the puzzle, otherwise there's nothing to `st_network_blend` with. Though I couldn't guess where to snip out of, whereas around [823] for dir_outlets seemed more indicated. If it isn't too large, put the full hyriv at the bottom and perhaps there's a formatting command to just make the box it scrolls in smaller...don't know. Something of a challenge in making an MRE for geographic data but worth the effort in what it yields for understanding.