# Convert string to canonical form with R

Tags: r, unicode, character-encoding, unicode-normalization

Here's an example of 2 strings that are not technically the same. I know for a fact that these 2 strings come from the same original value and have just been processed differently.

```r
str1 <- "Tapajós"
str2 <- "Tapajós"

# The 2 strings are different
str1 == str2
#> [1] FALSE

# Indeed the code points are different:
charToRaw(str1)
#> [1] 54 61 70 61 6a 6f cc 81 73
charToRaw(str2)
#> [1] 54 61 70 61 6a c3 b3 73

# Somehow stringi can figure out that they're actually the same
stringi::stri_cmp_equiv(str1, str2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I'd like to turn `str1` and `str2` into the same string -- which I understand is referred to as their canonical form.

I tried a few things playing around with `stringi` and encodings, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

The fact that `stringi::stri_cmp_equiv` recognises them as equivalent gives me hope though! I feel like I just lack the right keywords to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was indeed just missing a keyword: "unicode normalisation forms".

This is easily done with the `stri_trans_*` functions from `stringi`, typically `stringi::stri_trans_nfc`.

```r
str1 <- "Tapajós"
str2 <- "Tapajós"

# The 2 strings are different
str1 == str2
#> [1] FALSE

# But their "normalisation form C" or NFC is the same
stringi::stri_trans_nfc(str1)
#> [1] "Tapajós"
stringi::stri_trans_nfc(str1) == stringi::stri_trans_nfc(str2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>