# Filter does not work on Cyrillic alphabet with breve "й" in R

Tags: r, filter, cyrillic

I am kinda confused with the filter in R that seem to not work for Cyrillic alphabet with breve (й). Here is a simplified dataframe of my data which contains 1363 rows.

```
df <- data_frame(lex_1 = c('гей', "лесбиянка", "гей", "трансгендер", "гей", "лесбиянка"),
                 lex_2 = c("лесбиянка", "лесбиянка", "трансгендер", "трансгендер", "гей", "гей"),
                 w1w2 = c(10, 20, 25, 40, 65, 90),
                 w1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                 w2 = c(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
```

Now, from this dataframe, I want to filter just "гей" string on lex_1, so I used this code

```
kolokasi_gay <- df[df$lex_1=="гей",]
```

However, this is the result of the filter. It does not retrieve anything.
[image]

But when I change the word for the filter to "трансгендер", it worked perfectly fine.

```
kolokasi_gay <- df[df$lex_1=="трансгендер",]
```

[image]

Now I wonder, where did this go wrong? Why does it does not want to filter only words with breve "й"?

Your help is appreciated, thank you.

I tried to change the word that I want to filter, and it worked when the word does not have any breve diacritic.

Comment: After I fixed to `data.frame` instead of `data_frame`, I cannot reproduce the issue. Do `utf8ToInt(df$lex_1[1])` and `utf8ToInt("гей")` produce identical output on your system?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Misschien met een schone environment testen.

Comment: You can have different UTF representations of the same characters. One option is to always convert to the canonical form. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498789/convert-string-to-canonical-form-with-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a single Unicode for that character

```
utf8ToInt("й")
[1] 1081
```

Your dataframe seems to be using a merged version of "и" and "̆"

```
strsplit(df$lex_1[1], "")[[1]][3:4]
[1] "и" "̆" 

utf8ToInt("й")
[1] 1080  774
```

You can check for both with

```
grepl(
  paste0(intToUtf8("1080"), intToUtf8("774"), "|", intToUtf8("1081")),
    df$lex_1)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

or, more universal, replace the character altogether

```
df$new <- gsub(
  paste0(intToUtf8("1080"), intToUtf8("774")), intToUtf8("1081"), df$lex_1)

df$new == "гей"
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```